# Switch to tmpl=component in plugin code

Tags: templates, system-plugin

Just like using `tmpl=component` in a URL, I would like to change the `tmpl=` in a system plugin.

This, of course, does nothing:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$app->setTemplate('component', null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mimic something being set from the URL, you should push it into JInput:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$jinput->set('tmpl', 'component');
```

All code that runs after your plugin will see `tmpl=component`.